# Use of partitive articles

Tags: grammar, articles

When trying to write in Italian, I always feel insecure about the use of partitive articles. For instance, what should I say:

> In questa fotografia ci sono piccole case in legno

or

> In questa fotografia ci sono *delle* piccole case in legno?

> Nella mia scuola ci sono insegnanti italiani

or

> Nella mia scuola ci sono *degli* insegnanti italiani?

Comment: Personally I would not use the partitive in those cases.

Comment: It depends on what do you want to say. For example I'd interpret *Nella mia scuola ci sono insegnanti italiani* as if you wanted to say that *all* teachers are Italian, while, adding *degli*, you stress the fact that there are teachers who are *not* Italian. In the same way I'd interpret *In questa fotografia ci sono piccole case di legno* as if you were saying that the *only* things you can see in the picture are small wood houses, while adding *delle* you open the possibility that the picture simply contains some small wood houses, possibly with something else.

Comment: @Bakuriu, but it could also be the other way around: _ci sono insegnanti italiani_ might be interpreted as, _yes, there are at least two_, without specifying whether they are few or many; _ci sono degli insegnanti italiani_ could then be interpreted as _yes, there are a few_, at least two but few with respect to all others. So, if you want to state the mere existence of something (plural), you omit the partitive article; if you want to stress the relative scarcity of something, you use it.

Comment: @Bakuriu If I want to say that *all* teachers in my schoola are Italian, I'd use *gli insegnanti nella mia scuola sono italiani*.

Comment: I did *not* state that the sentence is *not* ambiguous. I just pointed out *one* possible interpretation. That's also why we can use other words to clarify what we mean (e.g. *ci sono solo insegnanti italiani*).

Comment: @Bakuriu I agree that the sentence can also have the meaning you pointed out, depending on intonation, pauses, context, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence

> *In questa fotografia ci sono delle piccole case in legno*

you are saying that you see a bunch of small wooden houses, more than two but relatively few. The form '*delle piccole case*' is the plural of '*una piccola casa*', the partitive article *delle* acts as the plural of indefinite article *una* and can easily be replaced with '*alcune*', i.e. '*some*' in English.

If you say

> *In questa fotografia ci sono piccole case in legno*

without any particular emphasis, most people would understand that there are at least two small wooden houses, without making specific assumptions whether these are few or many; as per egreg's comment, this might be enough. However, as pointed out by Bakuriu, depending on intonation, pauses, context, etc., people might even think that small wooden houses is all that you can really see in the picture.

The same applies to your other example.

My point of view is that the use of partitive articles depends on whether you intend to specify the relative scarcity of something or not. For example, in poetry, partitive articles can be omitted to create a sense of indefiniteness, vagueness:

> *Navi vanno laggiù e cercano nel vento il nuovo orientamento della rotta alle Indie*

Are all ships going there? Only few of them? More and more everyday? After all, the fact that ships are going there is more important than their number: they are changing the world alright.