# Meaning of "dei" in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

> Lui ha **dei** cavalli.

What does *dei* mean? The sentence comes from Duolingo, and it translates to

> He has horses.

I looked up *dei* in my dictionary, but I am still confused as to what it means in the sentence above.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6027/the-della-in-vorrei-delluva and http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2284/use-of-partitive-articles (and also http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6501/use-of-the-indefinite-article-in-italian-vs-english/6503#6503). If you still have doubts, please rephrase your question to cover something not covered in those previous questions.

Comment: Moreover, that is definitely not a dictionary. That is a quite useless app.

Comment: I guess I should have waited before I gave a possible duplicate answer! Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Dei* in this case is the so called *articolo partitivo* (partitive article). It means *an undefined number of*, and can be translated in English with some, a few, or, as in your example, nothing at all.
the name *partitivo* expresses the concept that the quantity you are speaking about is a part of something that is numerable, and is approximate or uncertain, but greater than one.
You use *degli* instead of *dei* whith the same rules that apply to the article *gli* instead of *i*.

You can think of the partitive article as the plural of the indefinite article, so, if you say:

> ho scritto un libro

you might also say

> ho scritto dei libri

Comment: Can this undecided number also be zero? :-)

Comment: @JackMaddington dei is used with enumerable objects, so "number" stands for natural number, not relative integer, rational, real or complex! So, it cannot be zero, negative or imaginary.

Comment: Many definitions of natural numbers, Peano's and other ones, include zero (but of course a partitive article implies a number greater than zero).

Comment: @DaG you are right, I will improve my answer. Thanks.